# is There any way to change default setting of beautify (VsCode Extension) configuration to indent innerHTML

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Hi There i want to know if there is a way to change default configuration of [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) extension in VsCode for all projects (make it default) . I always need to make **.jsonbeautifyrc** file in my root directory of project and write up under given code in it.

```
{
    "indent_inner_html": true
}
```

i want this setting to be implied to all projects without creating that extra **.jsonbeautifyrc** file in each of Project !

Comment: You wan to add it to VSCode globally? Everytime you use VSCode for any project?

Comment: yes ... btw Thanks for the answer .. u explained it really well @tHeSiD

Comment: YW! So the ans was correct? Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: yup the answer completely met my Expectation .. thanks for it ...

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want global settings for Beautify to persist across all you projects, you have to

1. Enable Beautify for all workspaces/projects ie globally (this is done by default)
2. You need to add the beautify settings to your `settings.json` file. Not the `settings.json` in your project folder. Global one

[image: Settings global]

3. You need to create a `beautify.config` object in that json file.
4. Copy paste all you beautify settings into that object like so

```
{
    "beautify.config": {
       "js": {
        "allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "jsonc", "jshintrc", "jsbeautifyrc"],
        "brace_style": "collapse", // [collapse|expand|end-expand|none] Put braces on the same line as control statements (default), or put braces on own line (Allman / ANSI style), or just put end braces on own line, or attempt to keep them where they are
        "break_chained_methods": false, // Break chained method calls across subsequent lines
        "e4x": false, // Pass E4X xml literals through untouched
        "end_with_newline": false, // End output with newline
        "indent_char": " ", // Indentation character
        "indent_level": 0, // Initial indentation level
        "indent_size": 2, // Indentation size
        "indent_with_tabs": false, // Indent with tabs, overrides `indent_size` and `indent_char`
        "jslint_happy": false, // If true, then jslint-stricter mode is enforced
        "keep_array_indentation": false, // Preserve array indentation
        "keep_function_indentation": false, // Preserve function indentation
        "max_preserve_newlines": 0, // Maximum number of line breaks to be preserved in one chunk (0 disables)
        "preserve_newlines": true, // Whether existing line breaks should be preserved
        "space_after_anon_function": false, // Should the space before an anonymous function's parens be added, "function()" vs "function ()"
        "space_before_conditional": true, // Should the space before conditional statement be added, "if(true)" vs "if (true)"
        "space_in_empty_paren": false, // Add padding spaces within empty paren, "f()" vs "f( )"
        "space_in_paren": false, // Add padding spaces within paren, ie. f( a, b )
        "unescape_strings": false, // Should printable characters in strings encoded in \xNN notation be unescaped, "example" vs "\x65\x78\x61\x6d\x70\x6c\x65"
        "wrap_line_length": 0 // Lines should wrap at next opportunity after this number of characters (0 disables)
       },
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    }
}
```

The last line tells VSCode to format JS with Beautify. You can add other languages to it and also your beautify.config.

Example

[image: Beautify settings.json]